# Determine all pairs of orthogonal subspaces in the set $\{M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Subspaces of $R^4$:

$$\begin{cases}
M_1 = \text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\}\\
M_2 = \text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\}\\
M_3 = \text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0& -1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0& 1& 0& -1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0& 0& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}\}\\
M_4 = \text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}-1& 1& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1& 0\end{bmatrix}\}\end{cases}$$

I'm supposed to determine all the pairs of orthogonal subspaces in the set

and determine which of these pairs are each others orthogonal complements.

I'm not really sure I understand the first question and my notes or google isn't helping.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. In the long run it is advisable to learn MathJax LaTeX typesetting as it generally  helps getting positive responses.

Comment: You can start by write down the definition of orthogonality and complementarity as they are prerequisites to solving the problem.

Comment: @mathreadler so $M_1$ and $M_2$ are a pair because the vector in $M_1$ is orthogonal to both vectors in $M_2$, and the same for $M_2$ and $M_4$ ?

Comment: Yes they are orthogonal complements to each other. Together they would build a bigger space. At least considering the standard inner product "dot product". Have you talked about inner products in your course yet?

Comment: @mathreadler So did I answer the second question? If so then I don't really understand the first question. I'm honestly not sure due to having been sick at home for the last 2 weeks,

Comment: @mathreadler   I've checked with a friend and he also got the same answers but he also doesn't understand what the first task is. Don't understand the difference in tasks

Comment: Complements together build a whole of something (in some sense).